# Jinja2 version for Python 3.4.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, jinja2

I'm writing my project in Python 3.4.4, which will run eventually on Ubuntu 14.04 (thus the Python 3.4.4, the latest supported for Ubuntu 14.04). I wanted to know what is the latest version of Jinja2 that is safe to install? I tried lookin at the Jinja docs but there was nothing about Python version requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja2 supports Python 3.4 in the latest version. If it drops the support for 3.4, you won't be able to install it anyway because of the [`python_requires` keyword in the setup script](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/274eff178d1dedcedf488a586f414a03952ac733/setup.py#L74):

```
setup(
    ...
    python_requires=">=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*",
)
```